# What are my options for cashing out or consolidating my Kiwisaver and Australian Super?

Tags: australia, new-zealand, superannuation

I am a New Zealand citizen who has been contributing to Kiwisaver for the last five years in New Zealand, and have since moved to Australia, where I am making Australian Super contributions here.

I'm looking for a general overview of what all my options are regarding using my Kiwisaver and Super.

I know for example that I can use my Kiwisaver to purchase a first home in New Zealand. Can I use my Australian Super for the same purpose?

Can I consolidate my Kiwisaver into my Australian Super, or vice versa? Would there be any tax advantages either way?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you can use your Australian super to buy a house.

With regards to transferring your Kiwisaver and Australian Super into each other, this is possible and should not attract any tax issues.

However combining them does offer one benefit, less fees paid to the investment providers, as both schemes would charge you fees for having funds in them.

Comment: "_as both schemes would charge you fees for having funds in them_" Would this not depend on how the fees are calculated? If each has a _minimum fee_, separate schemes might cost more, but 1% on 10,000 + 1% on 10,000 would be the same as 1% on a combined 20,000 (obviously, if one charges 1% and the other 2%, then merging into the 1% would be a no-brainer, _other things being equal_).

Comment: @TripeHound there may be fixed fees and insurance premiums.